# An Interesting Compile-Error on Topcoder

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This code gives a compile-error on Topcoder. On code::blocks, it compiles with 0 errors and 0 warnings, the vector is printed, but it exits with a non-zero value, that causes windows to display "InterestingDigits.exe has stopped working". Any help on this..?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class InterestingDigits
{
public:
vector <int> digits(int base)
{
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i=2; i<base; i++)
        if(base%i==1)
            v.push_back(i);
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
};

int main()
{
    int base;
    cin>>base;
    InterestingDigits id;
    id.digits(base);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the error is what? That `digits` is not returning a value?

Comment: Your code did not compile:

errors linking:

InterestingDigits-stub.o(.text+0x530): In function `main':
: multiple definition of `main'
InterestingDigits.o(.text+0x84): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `main' changed from 71 in InterestingDigits.o to 607 in InterestingDigits-stub.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: My code? Your code! Sorry, don't know Topcoder enough to help further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your method digits() should return a value, a vector < int >.

Maybe adding a "return v;" at the end?

Comment: This solves it on code::blocks. It exits with 0. But Topcoder's compiler says:

Comment: Your code did not compile:

errors linking:

InterestingDigits-stub.o(.text+0x530): In function `main':
: multiple definition of `main'
InterestingDigits.o(.text+0x84): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `main' changed from 71 in InterestingDigits.o to 607 in InterestingDigits-stub.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I don't know about Topcoders, but it looks like it is creating a "stubs" object. Maybe this link will help http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/139477/mutiple-definition-of-main-error-in-my-code.

Comment: Did Topcoders generated an InterestingDigits-stub.c file for you and then you included your own InterestingDigits.c?

Comment: Seems so. I removed my main function and all went well! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a vector. With your code, compiler would try to return something that caused the undefined behaviour. So adding "return v" should fix your issue.